# Error 400 using Basic Authentication API JSON on GAS

Tags: javascript, json, api, google-apps-script

I'm trying to download a file using the [Zamzar API](https://developers.zamzar.com/docs) through an app on Google App Scripts and I get the following error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Error>
    <Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
    <Message>Only one auth mechanism allowed; only the X-Amz-Algorithm 
      query parameter, Signature string parameter or the Authorization header 
      should be specified</Message>
    <ArgumentName>Authorization</ArgumentName>
    <ArgumentValue>Basic ENCODED ID </ArgumentValue>
    <RequestId> REQUEST ID </RequestId>  
    <HostId> HOST ID </HostId>
</Error>
```

Does anyone know what that is? I found something about resending the header authorization but I don't know how to do that on GAS.

Please find my code below:

```
function zamzar() {
  var url = "https://sandbox.zamzar.com/v1/jobs";
  var user = API KEY;
  var headers = {
    "Authorization": "Basic "+ Utilities.base64Encode(user+":"),
    "followRedirect": false
  };
  var options = {
    "method" : "post",
    "headers" : headers, 
    "muteHttpExceptions" : true,
  };  
  upload(url, headers, options);
}

function upload(url, headers, options) {
  var formData = {
    "source_file" : "http://www.sinduscon-rs.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/VALORES-DOS-CUBS.pdf", //pdf that will be converted to XLS
    "target_format" : "xls",
  }
  options["payload"] = formData;  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
  checkConversion(response, headers); 
}

function checkConversion(response, headers) {  
  Utilities.sleep(10000) // wait 10 seconds to finish conversion  
  var JSONresponse = JSON.parse(response, headers)
  var jobID = JSONresponse.id;
  var url = "https://sandbox.zamzar.com/v1/jobs/" + jobID;  
  var options = {
    "method" : "get",
    "headers" : headers, 
    "muteHttpExceptions" : true,
  };    
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);  
  var checkResponse = JSON.parse(response);
  download(checkResponse, headers); 
}

function download(checkResponse, headers) {
  var xlsID = checkResponse.target_files[0].id;
  var url = "https://sandbox.zamzar.com/v1/files/" + xlsID + "/content";
  var options = {
    "method" : "get",
    "headers" : headers,
    "muteHttpExceptions" : true,
  };    
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);

  Logger.log(response);
}
```

### Requests

upload():

```
[18-07-12 09:43:43:082 BRT] {headers={Authorization=Basic Yjc4NzZkZTAwM2ZkZjY3ZGE4MWNkMmMxNmRjMGQ2YTBlOTNkMTNlYTo=, followRedirect=false}, method=post, payload=source_file=http://www.sinduscon-rs.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/VALORES-DOS-CUBS.pdf&target_format=xls, followRedirects=true, validateHttpsCertificates=true, useIntranet=false, contentType=application/x-www-form-urlencoded, url=https://sandbox.zamzar.com/v1/jobs}
```

checkConversion():

```
[18-07-12 09:43:53:223 BRT] {headers={Authorization=Basic Yjc4NzZkZTAwM2ZkZjY3ZGE4MWNkMmMxNmRjMGQ2YTBlOTNkMTNlYTo=, followRedirect=false}, method=get, payload=, followRedirects=true, validateHttpsCertificates=true, useIntranet=false, contentType=null, url=https://sandbox.zamzar.com/v1/jobs/3282094}
```

download():

```
[18-07-12 09:43:53:423 BRT] {headers={Authorization=Basic Yjc4NzZkZTAwM2ZkZjY3ZGE4MWNkMmMxNmRjMGQ2YTBlOTNkMTNlYTo=, followRedirect=false}, method=get, payload=, followRedirects=true, validateHttpsCertificates=true, useIntranet=false, contentType=null, url=https://sandbox.zamzar.com/v1/files/35530845/content}
```

### Responses

upload():

```
[18-07-12 13:03:14:399 BRT] ({'zamzar-credits-remaining':"100", Server:"Apache", 'zamzar-test-credits-remaining':"64", Connection:"keep-alive", 'Content-Length':"354", Date:"Thu, 12 Jul 2018 16:03:14 GMT", 'Content-Type':"application/json; charset=utf-8"})
```

checkConversion():

```
[18-07-12 13:03:24:538 BRT] ({'zamzar-credits-remaining':"100", Server:"Apache", 'zamzar-test-credits-remaining':"60", Connection:"keep-alive", 'Content-Length':"501", Date:"Thu, 12 Jul 2018 16:03:24 GMT", 'Content-Type':"application/json; charset=utf-8"})
```

download()

```
[18-07-12 13:03:24:708 BRT] ({'Transfer-Encoding':"chunked", Server:"AmazonS3", Connection:"close", 'x-amz-request-id':"8C10EE520E590056", 'x-amz-id-2':"tpQ4wZSmNe3GMZV9aCOGA5DoOcZ36ONmYs2drJApbmg5wou/iOWJSkwhH3dKSiyi0ypU4GT9SUc=", Date:"Thu, 12 Jul 2018 16:03:23 GMT", 'Content-Type':"application/xml"})
```

Comment: @tehhowch, thanks for the reply! The `UrlFetchApp.fetch` that's generating the error is the one in the `download()` function.

Are you sure you can convert PDF to Google Sheets with Drive API? I could only find documentation for converting to Google Docs.

Comment: Apologies, you are correct - ocr/conversion of PDF will only map to a Docs file: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#importing_to_google_docs_types_wzxhzdk18wzxhzdk19. Consider building the request that would be sent and inspecting it for the multiple authorization parameters that the error references. [`getRequest`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#getrequesturl-params)

Comment: @tehhowch Thanks for the tip!
I attached the requests to the original question.

I don't really understand what that means. Do you have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31514336/only-one-auth-mechanism-allowed-only-the-x-amz-algorithm-query-parameter may be relevant to your situation. Are you able to review the response object that has the error? If so, comparing it to the request that was sent may be helpful too. [`HTTPResponse.getAllHeaders()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getAllHeaders())

Comment: @tehhowch thanks again! I've edited my question again to include the responses

Comment: @tehhowch did you have time to take a look in the responses? Thanks!